# Query returning Zero for paticular value in java

Tags: java

Hi all
  Am using a loop to execute a query but am getting zero for a particular column.

Example

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select id, (1+1) as regular from tab1 where id='"+i+"'");
    List result = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println(result.get(0).getRegular);
}
```

My Output is

```
2
0
2
0
0
0
2
0
2
0
```

Comment: You need check the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have no entries for id's 1,3,5,7 and 9? In that case, the query will return a null, and I think it is changed to a 0.